# Store certain data from a API Request in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am doing a API Request and I get this response.

```
{"status":"ok","meta":{"count":1},"[1]data":{"504511935":[{"statistics":{"battles":297}}]}}
```

[image]

Now is my question how do I manage to just get the last number "297" out of this.
I tried playing around with `json` and parameters and I just did not get it to work.
I just want to store the 279 (which will always be a number).

Thank you all in advance and have a nice day ;)

Comment: Which API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json library for this.

```
response_string = json.loads(response)
data = response_string["[1]data"]["504511935"][0]["statistics"]["battles"]
```

You should get your data like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 val = {"status":"ok","meta":{"count":1},"[1]data":{"504511935":[{"statistics": 
           {"battles":297}}]}}
        
 print(val["[1]data"]["504511935"][0]["statistics"]["battles"])
    
 297
```